# SharePoint 2013 Datepicker not styled

Tags: infopath, css, custom-masterpage, datepicker

I have a SharePoint 2013 publishing site with a relatively highly customized master page.  This master page is in use for both the system master page and the default master page.  Problem:  it causes the date picker on web-browsable InfoPath forms to be unstyled.  I switch back to seattle.master and it works as expected.

How can I fix this on my master page?  It's pretty thoroughly customized but the basics all seem to be there, when compared against seattle.master.  Is there some specific CSS file I can call up on the system master page to get the date picker to show up?  I don't care if this has to be manual I just need it to work.

Comment: You could use the IE Developer Toolbar or Chrome Developer tools to inspect the elements of the control when seattle.master is applied.  Then just add those styles to your own CSS.

Comment: -.-  You know that's simple enough that I can't believe I didn't think of it

Comment: I'll add it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the IE Developer Toolbar or Chrome Developer tools to inspect the elements of the control when seattle.master is applied. Then just add those styles to your own CSS.